# cakephp: php version problem (i think) need help

Tags: php, cakephp, version

so, i was building this website using cakePHP 1.2.1.8004 on my local and it was pre-developed until i got my hands on it, and yesterday i finally uploaded it so that it could go live, but apparently there's a lot of functions that were undefined and make my web goes all "white screen of death"

on my local i was using xampp 1.7.1 with php 5.2.9, and my online server is using php 5.2.17. i am thinking like the problems were coming from the php version difference, and i am trying to replicate it on my local by finding a xampp version which has the same php version, but apparently xampp doesn't have any bundle which includes php 5.2.17. now is there anyone who has had the same problem like i do, and confirm that the php version is really the source of the problem here so that i could reinstall the php on my server and downgraded it to pp 5.2.9? or should i look for another solution ?

thanks

Comment: It's unlikely that it's a cakePHP version issue as cakePHP is made to work with even PHP4. What are the error messages you are getting? Do you get a fatal_error as well?

Comment: few warnings and a fatal error, some date functions failure, i am not sure what function changed into what since the one who work on that fix was the other developer, i'll get back to you as soon as i get to know about this

Comment: PHP versions in the same series are (generally) not too different aside from bugfixes and versions of libraries.  Something like a PHP extension you had on xampp that's not on your host is more likely. As said above, just about the most useful thing you could add here are your actual error messages.

Comment: If you can, post the output of `phpinfo()` of both servers.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like a server rewrite issue. I would verify the URL rewrite is working correctly. Also, do you have debug turned on in core? It may shed some light on the issue as well.